Error handling in VBA - on error line gets registered but doesn't actually work
I have the following code:
Sub CopyRunsheetData()

    i = 375

For i = i To 999

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("Path" & "\" & "Run " & i & " Runsheet")
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("Path2" & "\" & "Run " & "0" & i)
    
ErrorHandler:
Next

End Sub

The problem is that it starts as expected for i=375 and because wbSource for i=375 does not exist as a file, it goes to ErrorHandler and Next i.
Now for i=376 I press F8 and the "On Error.." gets highlighted and therefor I assume registers, but wbSource for i=376 also does not exist but then I get the error:
enter image description here
Why does not go to the ErrorHandler again?
I also tried adding "Resume" before Next but then I get the "For without Next" error.
Alternatively, changing the code to:
Sub CopyRunsheetData2()

    i = 375

For i = i To 999

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("Path" & "\" & "Run " & i & " Runsheet")
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("Path2" & "\" & "Run " & "0" & i)
    
Next

End Sub

does the obvious and continues to wbTarget (and whatever steps I add after that). For the next i the error handling still works without issue in contrast to the code above.
I would like the code to go to next i if wbSource does not exist without having to go through the rest of the steps.
Can someone help?
Thank you in advance!

I actually found something that works from an answer on a different post.
Adding "On Error GoTo -1" before the original "On Error" solves the issue! Code is now:
Sub CopyRunsheetData()

i = 375

For i = i To 999

On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("Path1" & "\" & "Run " & i & " 
Runsheet")
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("Path2" & "\" & "Run " & "0" & i)

ErrorHandler:
Next

End Sub

